# What does ** mean?

Tags: go, hashmap

I'm reading `map.go` to have a deeper look at how `map` is implemented in Go.

I'm confused about what this piece of [code](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/map.go#L208) does:

```golang
func (b *bmap) overflow(t *maptype) *bmap {
    return *(**bmap)(add(unsafe.Pointer(b), uintptr(t.bucketsize)-sys.PtrSize))
}
```

Could anyone help me understand what `*(**bmap)` does here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `T` is a type then `*T` is also a type, specifically a pointer type, and since `*T` is a type then `**T` is also a type. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types

If `x` is an expression that produces a value then `*x` is a pointer indirection, or pointer dereference. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators

And if `T` is a type and `x` is an expression then `T(x)` is a conversion. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

---

So `**bmap` is a *type*, specifically a "pointer to a pointer to `bmap`" type.

Then `(**bmap)(add(...))` is a conversion that converts whatever the `add(...)` expression returns to a value of type `**bmap`.

And finally `*(**bmap)(...)` dereferences the result of that conversion by one pointer, leaving you with a value of type `*bmap`.